# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to react typescript, here i have props and its types, everything is fine except this part :           collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier] = true;
it gives error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

what is the right way of adding : collapseStates = {} to interface AA? as you can see it should contain strings `collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier]`
Any help or advice is appreciated

```js
  interface AA{
  action: "sites" | "analysers";
  actionArgs?: string;
  name: string;
  identifier: string;
}
  
  const Article: React.FC<AA> = (props) => {

  let [state, setState] = useState<AA>({
    actionArgs: props.actionArgs,
    collapseStates: {} ,
  });
 const handleExpandClick = (event, key) => {
setState({
  collapseStates: {
    ...state.collapseStates,
    [key]: !state.collapseStates[key],
  },
});
  };

 const initialize = () => {
    let collapseStates = {};
    articles.map((el: AA) => {
      collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier] = true;
      return;
    });

    setState({
      ...state,
      collapseStates: collapseStates,
    });
  };
  }
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can type `collapseStates` as a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html):

```
interface AA{
  ...
  collapseStates: Record<string,boolean>;
}
```

Comment: i still get same error

Comment: Just make a sandbox that reflects the error, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i cant put more code than that, but i did exactly as you said and still getting same error